# Horizontal list to vertical list and vice versa - Sublime Text 2

Tags: list, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, horizontallist, vertical-text

I can't remember where I saw it or read it, but appearantly there is a shortcut for transforming a horizontal list of words seperated with commas or even without commas, into a vertical list allowing me to quickly build a UL with LI tags for the vertical list.

I just need the shortcut to make a vertical list out of a common sentence, I have a windows 8 OS.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Select the text you want to convert
2. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> on Windows

Also here is a list of some more useful shortcuts
https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html

Other great resources

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/

https://tutsplus.com/course/improve-workflow-in-sublime-text-2/

https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/customization/key_bindings.html

Comment: That works for the vice versa what I'm looking for, but do you know the shortcut for making a vertical list a horizontal? I tried [Ctr] + [J] and it only worked for turning a vertical list into a horizontal.

Comment: You don't by any chance know how to do this the vice versa way do you? So i have a sentence and want to make each word a list item.

Comment: The key binding for Join Lines has changed to Cmd+Shift+J on Mac. (MacOS Ventura 13.3.1)

Answer (score 7):

for vise versa - horizontal to vertical

suppose not the best way but i use it

works for lists such as A,B,C,... maybe also possible for other

1) find all {your delimiter} (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

2) remove multi selection from delimiter (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd> <kbd>-></kbd>)

3) <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note:
Even Alt + F3 does the same in one stroke !!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> will convert vertical to horizontal.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> will convert vertical to horizontal

Comment: I think you should read your answer carefully. It seems, to me, that you have *one* of the actions described incorrectly ... or do both actions perform the same task?

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+J on Windows work,thanks

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-H (Find and Replace)

Find = "," or your delimiter
Replace with = "\n"

Make sure, the EXTENDED radio button is selected in the Search Mode block

[Find and Replace values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bpjI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the text you want to convert
2. ctrl+shift+j